# ValueError: `sample_weight` argument is not supported when using dataset as input

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I would like to train a keras model and use sample weight. My data source is of type tf.data.dataset. Got the following error when using the `sample_weight` argument of `model.fit` function.

```
ValueError: `sample_weight` argument is not supported when using dataset as input.
```

The code looks like:

```
model.fit(tf_train_dataset,
          epochs=epochs,
          verbose=self.verbose,
          batch_size=batch_size,
          callbacks=callbacks,
          sample_weight=sample_weights
          steps_per_epoch=self.steps_per_epoch,
          use_multiprocessing=True,
```

`tf_train_dataset` is created by `tf.data.Dataset.from_generator`. How could I pass weights for each sample and apply it to the loss and finally training?

Comment: You should add it as the 3rd dimension, [train_and_evaluate#sample_weights](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/train_and_evaluate#sample_weights)

Comment: Thanks that solved it! You should post this as answer

Comment: Just posted it with a dummy example as it follows the same logic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While using `tf.data.Dataset` API, sample weights should be another tuple in the dataset following order: `(input_batch, label_batch, sample_weight_batch)`.

Dummy example:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from sklearn.utils.class_weight import compute_sample_weight

x_train = np.random.randn(100,2)
y_train = np.random.randint(low = 0, high = 5, size = 100, dtype = np.int32)
weights = compute_sample_weight(class_weight='balanced', y=y_train)

train_data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_train, y_train, weights))
```

For more you can refer [the docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/train_and_evaluate#sample_weights).